# ASP.NET MVC Telerik upload control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a telerik async upload control in my asp.net mvc project like below:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("file")
        .Async(a => a
            .Save("Save", "Upload")
            .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
            .AutoUpload(true)
        )
    )
```

I refactored a little bit this form into async excel file validation instead of saving files.

Now I'm wondering how can I pass the file from telerik upload control to my own action, which takes parameters (HttpPostedFileBase file) on the external button click for example.

```
 public void Action(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I need to pass loaded file from upload control like in the picture below to action:

[telerik ctrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpK1h.png)

Any jQuery advice?

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this at all?  How is the `Action()` method being invoked?  This example seems incomplete.

Comment: Well in jQuery script I would like to get loaded file like in the picture and then post it to the controller/action as HttpPostedFileBase after external button  click.